# Flutter: How to manually set index for builder?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm currently stuck with setting the index here. I've tried various ways to set the index but the index's value cant be changed. This method is comes from the package :

```
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tindercard
```

Since I'm building cards, I might need to go back in index to properly sync with the back button which brings back the card. But the builder's index just keeps adding even if I perform a decrement inside the builder. This is the code I have of the builder:

```
  Widget _cardBuild() {
    return TinderSwapCard(
      orientation: AmassOrientation.BOTTOM,
      totalNum: articleList.length != null ? articleList.length + backCount : 0,
      stackNum: 3,
      swipeEdge: 1.0,
      animDuration: 50,
      maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
      maxHeight: 410.1,
      minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
      minHeight: 410,
      cardBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Card(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          ),
          child: Conditional.single(
            context: context,
            conditionBuilder: (BuildContext context) => pendingBack > 0,
            widgetBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
              return _generateCards(cardIndex);
            },
            fallbackBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
              return _generateCards(index);
            },
          ),
        );
      },
      cardController: controller = CardController(),
      swipeUpdateCallback: (DragUpdateDetails details, Alignment align) {
        /// Get swiping card's alignment
        if (align.x < 0) {
          //Card is LEFT swiping
        } else if (align.x > 0) {
          //Card is RIGHT swiping
        }
      },
      swipeCompleteCallback: (CardSwipeOrientation orientation, int index) {
        if (index == articleList.length) {
          setState(() {
            isOutOfCards = true;
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            cardIndex++;
          });
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

A sample screenshot of the app:
[[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Why are you asking a new question when you posted this one 2 days ago?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60807504/flutter-how-to-recover-removed-cards
Your purpose still remain the same, right ?

Comment: Yeah sorry about that I was planning to delete that one after all the major changes I made